# How to remove ASP.NET MVC OKTA Forms Authentication for local test

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, web, okta

I am working  on a client solution that requires new features and functionality to be added to a cloud web application with OKTA Authentication. I've been able to create the new models, views, and controllers as per requirement, with no errors when I build the solution. When I run the application to test locally, the views load in the browser but no data and functionality, and a redirect on the URL, either running in the preconfigured DEV, STG, or PRD Azure environments.

< http://localhost:1080/AuthServices/SignIn?ReturnUrl=%2f >

It's not finding the authentication form, it has no user information, and the site is not loading properly. I've tried different thing, including removing the authentication all together, and setting authentication to non /  in the web.config. The only thing I've not done yet is testing on the publishing side.  Everything with OKTA is setup correctly as it's working fine with the last deployed version of the solution, . Non non of those configurations were changed.

How can work around or disable this entirely so that I can test the application locally?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would recommend trying to post this on the Okta forums. They are fantastic about replying there, and I don't really see many users of Okta on here. I ran into a similar problem trying to get help for an application I wrote a few months back.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You are not testing a section of the application that deals with user-specific information, for instance, a user profile page.

To temporarily disable Okta authentication:

1. In `Startup.cs`, comment out this line:
   `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Gilson.GRMS.Startup))]`
2. Add this line to the `appSettings` section of `Web.config`: 
   `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>`
3. Comment out the `[Authorize]` attribute on each controller action referenced by the section of the application you are trying to test.

Unfortunately, #3 above means that if you want to disable Okta authentication for the entire site, you might have to comment out a lot of `[Authorize]` lines.